# unable to read large file in azure app service

Tags: spring-boot, azure-appservice

We have spring boot application running in azure app service to do some ETL operations on CSV files.
A file will be put into instance local directory from where application will be picking the file and process it.  We are facing an issue if the uploaded file is bigger than >10 MB. Reader is not able to read the file and returning null . We are using supercsv to process the csv
file .

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);

 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

CsvListReader reader = new CsvListReader(bufferedReader, CsvPreference.EXCEL_NORTH_EUROPE_PREFERENCE);
 List<String> read = reader.read();
`
```

reader.read() method returns null.The issue is happening only in azure app service (linux) and working in local perfectly with the same.

Can anyone help me to find out what the issue is here ?

Comment: What's your file path? Make sure it's not accessing some path that doesn't exist

Comment: file is there in correct path and its working fine if file size is less than 10 MB